# how to use uibmodal with a scope sub parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Using angular-boostrap's uibmodal, I want to give my modal a namespaced set of scope parameters to work with. I need these scope parameters to live in my parent to passed on to other controllers, but I also don't want my modal to have access to my entire parent scope. So what I really want to do is this:

```
//parent controller
$scope.selector = { ... }

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: false,
  controller: 'SelectorController',
  scope: $scope.selector
  templateUrl: 'selector.tpl.html'
});
```

However I get:

```
angular.min.js:111 TypeError: c.$new is not a function
at angular.bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8
```

Is there a pattern to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

There is some option, you can pass params from your current scope to modal scope, just add currentUserId inside param of your Controller

```
resolve: {
        currentUserId: function () {
          return row.entity._id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with is to actually create a new scope variable with the `$rootScope.$new()` module [documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

This allowed me to instantiate my modal with

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: false,
  controller: 'SelectorController',
  scope: $scope.selector,
  templateUrl: 'selector.tpl.html'
});
```

My modal now has a namespaced scope that it can play with, yet all changes made to that scope in available from my parent scope.